# installer prerequisite in VS2010 Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, windows-installer, add-in

VS2010 Setup project, Excel AddIn, C#,  ExcelDNA, NetOffice

1. I use VS2010 setup project to create installer. 
   Click Prerequisite properties of the setup project, I see Windows Installer 3.1 and Windows Installer 4.5 are listed in prerequisite list. 
   In VS2008, I checked Windows Installer 3.1 in prerequisite (though I do not know why?).
   In VS2010, I wonder maybe I should check windows installer 4.5 in prerequisite list. 
   I wonder if I need check it and why?
2. Another thing is  Shared Add-in support Update for Microsoft .NET framework 2.0 (KB908002) is listed in prerequisites list, too.  Wonder if I need it? My AddIn is target .NET 35 Sp1
3. My addIn target .NET framework 3.5 sp1 in VS2008, now I move to VS2010, in setup project, I can check either .NET 3.5 SP1 or .NET 4.0 as prerequisite.  Does my target .NET framework have to be the same version as that in prerequisite list?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit?

Comment: Thank you, Deepansh. Questions edited and hope they are clear. Let me know if they are still not.

Answer (score 2):

> In VS2010, I wonder maybe I should check windows installer 4.5 in
>   prerequisite list. I wonder if I need check it and why?

You should check it only if you need to use [Windows Installer 4.5 features](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288).

> Another thing is Shared Add-in support Update for Microsoft .NET
>   framework 2.0 (KB908002) is listed in prerequisites list, too. Wonder
>   if I need it? My AddIn is target .NET 35 Sp1

You should answer this question. Does your add-in need it in order to work correctly? Did you add a .NET Framework prerequisite which includes this update?

> Does my target .NET framework have to be the same version as that in
>   prerequisite list?

It's the other way around. First you determine the .NET Framework version your add-in needs and then add it as a prerequisite.

Comment: thanks, Cosmin. Found out, I do not need KB908002.  and also for the target framework version can be different from prerequisite list though usually they should match. In case they are different, VS will give a warning message but addin should still work fine